# Parsing html in haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to parse the `a` links from the main part (`<article>`) of a blog post. I have adapted what I found on [FPComplete](https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/starting-with-haskell/libraries-and-frameworks/text-manipulation/tagsoup) but nothing is printed out. (The code does not work as far as I can see as running it on the online IDE and with the Bing target also produces no links.)

In GHCI I can simulate the first line of parseAF and that gets me a large record, which I take to be correct. But `cursor $// findNodes &| extractData` returns `[]`

I've tried regex but that wasn't happy trying to find such a long piece of text.

Can anyone help?

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module HtmlParser where

import Network.HTTP.Conduit (simpleHttp)
import Prelude hiding (concat, putStrLn)
import Data.Text (concat)
import Data.Text.IO (putStrLn)
import Text.HTML.DOM (parseLBS)
import Text.XML.Cursor (Cursor, attribute, element, fromDocument, ($//), (&//), (&/), (&|))

-- The URL we're going to search
url = "http://www.amsterdamfoodie.nl/2015/wine-beer-food-restaurants-troost/"

-- The data we're going to search for
findNodes :: Cursor -> [Cursor]
findNodes = element "article" &/ element "a"

-- Extract the data from each node in turn
extractData = concat . attribute "href"

cursorFor :: String -> IO Cursor
cursorFor u = do
     page <- simpleHttp u
     return $ fromDocument $ parseLBS page

-- Process the list of data elements
processData = mapM_ putStrLn

-- main = do
parseAF :: IO ()
parseAF = do
     cursor <- cursorFor url
     processData $ cursor $// findNodes &| extractData
```

**UPDATE** After more exploring it seems that the problem lies with `element "article"`. If I replace that with `element "p"`, which is OK in this instance as the only `p`s are in the `article` anyway, then I get my links. Pretty weird....!!

Comment: If I look for the source for that website the only `<article>` tag doesn't actually contain any links in it, it would appear that it's actually populated by javascript that runs after the HTML is loaded.

Comment: Eh No.  `<article>` runs from line 185 to 267 and includes numerous links - some in the text and some wrapped by wordpress around images (which I actually don't need)

Comment: Ah, yes, you would appear to be correct.  Can you verify that when you download it with `simpleHttp` that you get the same content?  I would try it myself but I'm currently behind a corporate proxy that makes it difficult to do that.

Answer (score 6):

I think you can do this in a very readable way with HXT by composing filters:

```
{-# LANGUAGE Arrows #-}

import Text.XML.HXT.Core
import Text.XML.HXT.Curl
import Text.XML.HXT.TagSoup

links url = extract (readDocument
  [ withParseHTML yes
  , withTagSoup
  , withCurl      []
  , withWarnings  no
  ] url)

extract doc = runX $ doc >>> xmlFilter "article" >>> xmlFilter "a" >>> toHref

xmlFilter name = deep (hasName name)

toHref = proc el -> do
   link    <- getAttrValue "href" -< el
   returnA -< link
```

You can call this in the following way:

```
links "http://www.amsterdamfoodie.nl/2015/wine-beer-food-restaurants-troost/"
```

Comment: Does assume the html is xml compliant?

Comment: Since the option "withParseHTML" is set, an HTML parser is used instead of an XML parser. So it is assumed to be valid HTML.

Comment: A bit more readable still with the redundant parents in `extractLinks` removed.

Comment: You are right, I removed the unnecessary parentheses.

Comment: Hey, thanks. I'll try it tomorrow. I suppose we should consider ourselves lucky to have such a choice of tools but it does make the density of examples to work from low

Comment: Might I ask why, in the definition of `extractLinks` you use a return in the end? I think a bind with a return makes it identity, so we can just ignore that return?

Answer (score 2):

OK, so the problem was that `&/` only looks at immediate children, whereas `&//` will go through all descendants

```
findNodes = element "article" &// element "a"
```